# eclipse: sort in eclipse outline for .js files broken

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I've just upgraded to the latest Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers - Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0).
In this version the outline for JS files seems to be broken. The order inside an function is always alphabetically and not in the order of the written code (top to bottom). Clicking the sort ouline button doesn't change the order inside the function. Any ideas?

Outline without sorting:

[image]

Code

```
function outer() {
    function e() {
    
    }
    function d() {
    
    }
    function c() {
    
    }
    function b() {
    
    }
    function a() {
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously, that's not the original Eclipse. It seems you have installed the _Dev Style_ or _Darkest Dark_ theme by Genuitec which tries to cheat the Eclipse open source license by patching Eclipse at runtime (or to be more precise via loadtime weaving). This can cause issues and slow down Eclipse. Can you reproduce it with a fresh Eclipse installation without additional plugins and with a fresh workspace?

Comment: Yes, it's the Darkest Theme. I set up a new eclipse with a new workspace and without any plugins but unfortunately I run into the same problem as before. It seems like eclipse has a problem with nested functions.

Comment: Then please update the screenshots of your question which should also show the editor and provide an example file (as text) with which this can reproduced.

Comment: Added a new Screenshot and an example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a **known issue** of [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper):

[**Issue #534: *Outline sort order cannot be changed***](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/issues/534)

Please comment on the issue. Add a *thumb up*  (+1) reaction emoticon  to the issue description to vote for the issue.